# Unable to read excel file sent from POST request in Flask?

Tags: python-3.x, angularjs, pandas, flask, python-requests

I am trying to send an excel file from my AngularJS frontend and read/parse the columns in my Flask app. However, I am getting the error

```
File "/var/task/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 296, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 304, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "/var/task/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 867, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "/var/task/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py", line 480, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/var/task/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 351, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/var/task/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py", line 491, in load_workbook
    return load_workbook(
  File "/mnt/accesspoint/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "/mnt/accesspoint/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "/mnt/accesspoint/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py", line 1269, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py", line 1364, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("Bad magic number for central directory")
zipfile.BadZipFile: Bad magic number for central directory
```

What is the problem that's causing this?

Angularjs html

```
<nz-card nzTitle="Upload File" bordered={false} style="flex: 1 1 auto;">
            <nz-upload 
            [nzCustomRequest]="handleUpload"
            [(nzFileList)]="fileList" 
            (nzChange)="handleChange($event)"
            [nzDownload]="handleDownload"
            [nzAccept]="fileType"
            >
                <p class="ant-upload-drag-icon"><i nz-icon nzType="inbox"></i></p>
                <p class="ant-upload-text">
                    Click or drag CSV/Excel a file to this area to upload
                </p>
            </nz-upload>
        </nz-card>
```

Angularjs component

```
handleUpload = (item: any) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(item.name, item.file);

    var upload = this.httpClient.post(this.SERVER_URL, formData).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log("success");
        item.onSuccess(item.file);
        if (typeof (res) === 'object') {
          console.log(res);
        }
        item.file;
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log("failure")
        item.onError(err, item.file);
      }
    )
```

Flask python

```
def upload():
    file = request.files['file']
    print("request", file)

    df = pd.read_excel(file, index_col=0, engine='openpyxl')
    print(df)
```

Logs (before the error message)

```
request <FileStorage: 'sample_excel.xlsx' ('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')>
```

I have also tried reading it using with

```
 with open(file, 'rb') as f
```

But with that I get an error stating `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileStorage`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're reading the FileStorage object, not the file itself.
`file = request.files['file']` is the `FileStorage` object. To access the file in it, you have to supply `file.read()` to pandas. I think its also better practice to use .get(), so `request.files.get('file').read()` will get you the actual excel file itself.